# What is the difference between a language and a framework?

Tags: frameworks, programming-languages, definition

Can someone give me a clear, concise definition of the difference between a programming language and a framework?  I have scoured the web and been unable to find an adequate definition.

For extra credit, is it possible for a language and a framework to become so inextricably linked that there IS no difference, or is there such a clear line between them that this isn't possible?

Comment: Perhaps an example of your EC question would be the NextStep framework as part of Objective-C.  Not exactly inextricable, but pretty close...

Comment: If a language were "inextricably linked" to a framework in any fashion, then the framework would be by definition part of the language.

Comment: There are tons of languages you can use NeXTStep/OpenStep/Cocoa with: Objective-C++, Objective-Modula-2, Ruby, Nu, FScript, ... And you can use Objective-C without NeXTStep/OpenStep/Cocoa. The relationship between Objective-C and NeXTStep is similar to the one between C and POSIX: they were invented together and integrate well, but you can use POSIX without C (e.g. with C++, OCaml, Perl) and you can use C without POSIX (e.g. with Win32, NeXTStep, or with no environment *at all*, e.g. on embedded devices or when writing OS kernels.)

Comment: @Jorg, absolutely.  A language, by definition must stand alone.  However, my only point was that writing objective-c code without the NS library is orders of magnitude more difficult because it provides many of the core data abstractions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A language is syntax, grammar, semantics (and perhaps a core library) that implementers are required to support.  A framework is a *cohesive* set of library code that together simplifies programming in any given language.

Comment: A framework doesn't have to written in the language.  It just has to be available to the language.

Comment: @Jorg - In that case could you specify the difference between a library and a framework?

Comment: @Ender: the difference is Inversion Of Control: you call the library, but the framework calls you. BTW: this question has benn discussed extensively on SO.

Comment: @Ender: The difference is cohesion. Yes, a framework is a set of libraries, but these libraries work well together and have consistent syntactics and semantics.

Comment: @Jorg: I disagree that what you're describing is an important difference, much less the difference between a library and a framework (which seems like a very wishy-washy distinction to me -- a framework is just a kind of library.)  I agree more with Frederick's usage, and I don't mind his edit to my answer (although I want to emphasize that a framework is entirely comprised of code, not a specification.)  Feel free to attempt to convince me otherwise.

Comment: Addendum:  I changed my mind without Jorg having to convince me.  It looks like framework has a technical definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework  However, I think my answer still encapsulates the key distinction, which is that a language is a specification while a framework is made of code.

Comment: I've yet to see anything that calls itself a framework that simplified anything for me (examples that come to mind at the moment: Java EE, django, rails, PHP, Erlang's OTP). Someone care to share a counterexample? Also I agree 100% with Jörg here.

Comment: @David in that case, it's a compiler, not a framework. Nodejs is not a framework that lets Windows execute JavaScript...

Answer (score 4):

---

An **application framework** is the organizational structure of any application's code, including choices for conventions in files/folders, classes/functions, etc.

An **application framework product** is any tool that helps generate the framework for an application.

An **application design pattern** is any conceptual approach for organizing code at the application level.

An **software language** is a language-based tool that can be used to build applications, utilities, libraries, frameworks, etc.

A **library** is any extension in functionality to the native compiled functionality of a language.

A **standard library** is a library packaged with the language product itself.

An **external library** is a library outside of the language product itself and is either called remotely or installed locally.

A **code-generator** is any tool that dynamically generates permanent runtime code based on the developer's input.

---

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the clear line between language and framework, i suppose you can count DSLs (Domain Specific Languages) as constructs that are both a Language and a Framework ( as it is a Framework in the original Language it is build upon).

Lisp is the only language i can think of now that may blur such distinction:

"The name LISP derives from "LISt Processing". Linked lists are one of Lisp languages' major data structures, and Lisp source code is itself made up of lists. As a result, Lisp programs can manipulate source code as a data structure, giving rise to the macro systems that allow programmers to create new syntax or even new domain-specific languages embedded in Lisp."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)

Answer (score 2):

I hope i can explain using an example.

Dot net is a framework which consists of large libraries and supports many
programming languages.. C# is a programming language through which you can give
instruction to a machine mainly computer.. Now if your source code is in C#
you can use Dot net framework libraries and the source code which is written in other
languages..

Answer (score 1):

At my point, a programming language looks like bunch of stuff (syntax,grammar, semantics etc.) which people are already combine them into one more convenient, more useful, easier to use, and more enjoyable - a framework, and I love to have a framework before start making a program.

I know some programming languages like C, PHP, ASP, Python, Java, and some frameworks like Yii, Zend, Pygame, Struts. All I see is there can be many frameworks built from a programming language, but a framework is built from only on programming language.

Answer (score -1):

A programming language is a specified, standardized method of communication between the programmer and computer (in modern languages, technically it's between programmer and compiler, which "interprets" your code into simpler instructions the computer can work with). It is a pure abstraction that specifies its structure, syntax and semantics; implementations of the language are generally considered part of the environment in which the programmer develops, and incorporate the compiler and any virtual machine implementation.

A framework is a standardized set of pre-written code libraries designed to be used and reused by developers, and is again tied more to the environment. An environment is the intersection of the language, framework, virtual machine or runtime (an abstraction layer in which managed or interpreted code is translated from a machine-independent form into native code) and machine (the hardware layer on which native instructions are executed).