# Does Javascript and Jquery languages are enough to make a working web messenger application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

Can we make a web based messenger application through the use of just these two languages javascript and jquery?

Comment: Do you count Node.js as the same as JavaScript?

Comment: Only client side? Yes.

Comment: @Max **yes** ..

Comment: jQuery is not a language...it is a javascript library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will at least need to learn some basics of HTML as well.
(Hopefully) you also want to style your application, which means you should learn at least some CSS.

As far as programming languages go you will however need to know JavaScript and can use jQuery (among other things) to manipulate DOM.

Many modern applications however user React or Angular heavily to make the application building process easier in the long run.

You will also need to store your data somewhere, which means either server-side code and learning how to use a database such as mySQL, MongoDB or CouchDB to name a few (noSQL such as MongoDB or CouchDB are probably more appropriate for a messaging app). Or make it easier on yourself and use Firebase or something similar to store and retrieve data as well as handle user account and authentication.

I know all this may seem overwhelming, but making web apps involves a lot of moving parts.

### SUMMARY

If you are starting out, I would recommend simpler challenges than a web app, but if that is what you are set on, the easiest in my opinion would be:

- HTML + CSS + JQUERY (this is how your app UI is handled)
- JAVASCRIPT (connects UI and data)
- FIREBASE (stores data and enables user management and authentification)

**Resources** to help you get started:

- https://www.codecademy.com
- https://firebase.google.com

Comment: Oh, and just to be precise, jQuery is not a language, it's a framework (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763045/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-and-a-framework)

Comment: This is a very step to step guide,walks you through thank you so much!